# Prolog - trying to determine order of store visits based on given facts

Tags: prolog

I am trying to determine the order that someone visits the following stores, and buys the following items:

**Stores:**

```
1. kingtoots
2. leftorium
3. sprawlmart
4. trynsave
```

**Items:**

```
1. saxophone
2. dress
3. pacifier
4. slingshot
```

**Here are the given facts:**

```
1. He bought the saxophone book at King Toots
2. The store he visited immediately after buying the slingshot was not Sprawl-Mart
3. The Leftorium was his second stop
4. Two stops after leaving Try-N-Save, he bought the pacifier
```

After a few attempts of writing Prolog facts based on the given information, here is what I came up with:

```
purchase(saxophone, king_toots).
purchase(greendress, X).
purchase(pacifier, X).
purchase(slingshot, X).

store(leftorium, X).
store(king_toots, saxophone).
store(sprawlmart, X).
store(trynsave, X).

stop1(X, Y) :- store(X, Y), purchase(Y, X).
stop2(X, Y) :- store(leftorium, X), purchase(X, leftorium).
stop3(X, Y) :- store(X, Y), purchase(Y, X).
stop4(X, Y) :- store(X, Y), purchase(Y, X).
```

However, when I run this in SWI-Prolog, I get the following error:

```
  2 ?- stop2(X, Y).
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: stop2/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

This is more of a "please guide me in the right direction" with writing the facts/logic rather than "why am I getting this error." I am new to Prolog and logical programming, so any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a lot of warnings about singletons, variables appearing only once in a clause. Prolog is all about relations, you should write predicates that hold true relating arguments, and a singleton is pretty useless. A simple solution schema could be

```
order_stores(L) :-
    L =[[_,_,1],
        [_,_,2],
        [_,_,3],
        [_,_,4]],
    facts1(L),
    facts3(L),
    facts4(L),
    facts2(L).

facts1(L) :-
    member([saxophone,kingtoots,_],L).
...
```

note that facts2/1 is last: that's because simple negation in Prolog needs instantiated arguments... otherwise, use dif/2.